# how to apply setValidity to element?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, validation

I have directive to verify same password entered by user. But inside directive I want to `setValidity = true` for both the input elements

```
.directive('equalsTo', function() {
        return {
            require: 'ngModel',
            link: function(scope, elm, attrs, ctrl) {
                scope.$watch(attrs.ngModel, function() {
                    console.log(ctrl.$viewValue);
                    debugger;
                    if ($('#' + attrs.id).val() === $(attrs.equalsTo).val()) {
                        ctrl.$setValidity('equalsTo', true);
                        //here I want to apply $(attrs.equalsTo).setValidity('equalsTo', true);
                    } else {
                        ctrl.$setValidity('equalsTo', false);
                        //here I want to apply $(attrs.equalsTo).setValidity('equalsTo', false);
                    }
                });
            }
        };
    });
```

I want to apply `setValidity` on element like `$(attrs.equalsTo)`

```
<input id="newPassword" name="newPassword" ng-model="newPassword" type="password"
                                       class="form-control" placeholder="new password" ng-minlength="5" equals-to="#verifyNewPassword">
<input id="verifyNewPassword" name="verifyNewPassword" ng-model="verifyNewPassword" type="password"
                                       class="form-control" placeholder="verify new password" equals-to="#newPassword">
```

Answer (score 1):

There is a better way to do it, pass in the ngModelController of the dependent input. So html becomes

```
<input id="newPassword" name="newPassword" ng-model="newPassword" type="password"
                                       class="form-control" placeholder="new password" ng-minlength="5" equals-to="form.verifyNewPassword">
<input id="verifyNewPassword" name="verifyNewPassword" ng-model="verifyNewPassword" type="password"
                                       class="form-control" placeholder="verify new password" equals-to="form.newPassword">
```

Here i am assuming the name of the form being

`<form name='form'>`

substitute it with the name your form has.

Then change you directive definition to read data from the other ngModelController.

```
.directive('equalsTo', function() {
        return {
            require: 'ngModel',
            link: function(scope, elm, attrs, ctrl) {
                scope.$watch(attrs.ngModel, function() {
                    console.log(ctrl.$viewValue);
                    var otherController=scope.$eval(attrs.equalsTo);
                    if (ctrl.$viewValue===otherController.$viewValue) {
                        ctrl.$setValidity('equalsTo', true);
                        otherController.setValidity('equalsTo', true);
                    } else {
                        ctrl.$setValidity('equalsTo', false);
                        //here I want to apply
                        otherController.setValidity('equalsTo', false);
                    }
                });
            }
        };
    });
```

Comment: Issue here, when this directive is called first time by id#newPassword at that time there does not exists element #verifyNewPassword

Comment: better to pass scope variable to $watch

Comment: Check $watch documentation, it take new and old value as params. You can use those to see if the watch needs to set validity.